# Construct a circle tangent to an arc and a line through a given point

Tags: geometry

I am trying to draw a circle tangent to the line at point P and tangent to the arc.

[image]

The thick lines on the image above represent a curtain wall in a building. The point P (the end of the curve) should align with a grid at the exact location.

On a Cad software, I can fillet between the line and the curve with different radii to get a tangent as close as possible to point P.

I also tried drawing an intermediate curve between the line and the arc so it intersects the line perpendicular to P at the center point. But all these solutions are approximate and don't give an accurate tangent.

A variation I have to this problem is drawing a circle tangent to two arcs through a given point at one arc.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Is that a circular arc? If so, what is the relation of the line to the arc? Such details would be needed for a solution.

Comment: Algebraically, $r = \frac{R^2 - OP^2}{2(R-d)}$ where $O$ is the center of the given circle and $d$ is the distance between $O$ and the given line. There are ways to construct this distance $r$ geometrically, but I'm not seeing an especially convenient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend your drawing as shown below. Let $O$ be the center of curvature of the arc; extend a line through $O$ parallel to the wall through $P$ so that it meets the perpendicular line through $P$ at a point $Q$.
Let the radius of the arc be $R$, and let $OQ = a$ and $PQ = b.$
Let $C$ be the (as yet unknown) center of the desired circle and $r$ the (as yet unknown) radius of that circle.

[image]

Then $\triangle OQC$ is a right triangle with right angle at $Q$,
legs $a$ and $b + r,$ and hypotenuse $R - r.$ By the Pythagorean Theorem,

$$(R - r)^2 = a^2 + (b + r)^2.$$

Expand both sides:
$$R^2 - 2Rr + r^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2br + r^2.$$

Cancel the $r^2$ on each side, collect the terms in $r$ on the right and the other terms on the left:
$$R^2 - a^2 - b^2 = 2(R + b)r.$$

Therefore
$$r = \frac{R^2 - a^2 - b^2}{2(R + b)}
= \frac{R^2 - (OP)^2}{2(R + b)}.$$

Comment: I see that while I was working on this, a similar result was posted as a comment. The answers are not equivalent. I think this one is correct. In any case it comes with a figure and derivation that can be checked.